# Is there a way to generalize petapoco select query

Tags: c#, petapoco

I'm trying to use PetaPoco ORM to get data from MySQL table. Below is the sample code to get only one record:

```
public void ShowEmployerDetails()
        {
            using (var db = new PetaPoco.Database ("mysql_mydb")) {
                try {
                    var employers = db.Query <Employers> ("SELECT * FROM Employer WHERE id = 123456789");
                    foreach(var e in employers) {
                        return e.EmployerName;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.Error (ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

There is need to pass the entity type in db.Query function. For each DB table, we need to define entities. In this case, the entity type is `<Employers>` and code is as:

```
public class Employers
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string EmployerName { get; set; }
    }
```

Is there any way that we can generalize the above select query also? For instance, I'm planning to get output using single query like:

```
PetaPocoQueryEntities <Employers>.GetDataFromEntities ("SELECT * FROM Employer WHERE id = 123456789", "EmployerName");
```

And the query could be something like below where entity type could be passed as generic type T and wonder if there is some way in providing column name and getting column value dynamically:

```
public static class PetaPocoQueryEntities <T> 
    {
        public static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public static T GetDataFromEntity (string sqlQuery, string colName )
        {
            using (var db = new PetaPoco.Database ("mysql_mydb")) {
                try {
                    var entityResults = db.Query<T> (sqlQuery);
                    foreach (var result in entityResults) {
                        log.Info(colName + " value is " + result.colName);
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    log.Error (ex.Message);
                }
                return colName;
            }
        }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is need to pass the entity type in db.Query function

Short answer - yes. PetaPoco uses this information to map the data from the query back to entity correctly

> Is there any way that we can generalize the above select query also? For instance, I'm planning to get output using single query like:

Yep, you could rig this up. [This integration test should get you started.](https://github.com/CollaboratingPlatypus/PetaPoco/blob/development/PetaPoco.Tests.Integration/Databases/BaseExecuteTests.cs)